# Insulating from static electricity

Tags: high-voltage, wire, insulation, static-electricity, electrostatic

I am happy to announce that my pocket extra-strong static electricity generator project is now complete and works well.

However there is one problem, I am often getting zapped severely (to the extent I get muscle contractions) by touching the wire that carries out the high voltage negative output even though it is supposedly insulated.

My guess is that the wire is too thin, what is the easiest way to solve this problem? Is it best that I insulate it further with hot glue?

Comment: Stray capacitance holds and couples energy insulation breakdown of plastic is about 5k ~8kV/mm

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Yes the negative output is much higher in voltage than my body, because of my body resistance and I get shocked because of the voltage difference.

Comment: There is no way to have 0V on the negative lead of a floating 20kV output. Using rubber insulated wire pairs , treat both as live.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist No I didn't said I have 0V at the negative lead of a floating 20kV output. In fact the negative output (that goes to ground) is where a number close to 20kV moves through. As far as I know it does not have to be 0, but just different than your skin in order to get shocked, because of the electrons jumping from one another.

Comment: What is your experimental intended use?

Comment: If my skin is same voltage than the HV output, I would not get shocked, if material b is 0V I will get zapped, but it will not hurt that much, I will just give electrons, if material b > my skin there is a serious discharge, where supposedly a repelling force is to be excerpted

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist It is a project mainly for fun and entertainment. I also use copper material tourniquet (because of the lesser resistance and better durability) to connect to my body and I must say that the feeling is amazing. I use 3 LG HG2 batteries in series with balancing BMS and a voltage level indicator. I threw away the step-up DC module, because with the 3 batteries I approximate 12V anyway

Comment: how amazing is it?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist You feel something like cold air stream between your hand and the ground (I use glass table as a ground, because of sizes and material and the limiting aspects) as well as small needles sort of sensation. I am not sure to why this feels like so though.

Comment: You’re quite mad, you know.

Comment: @BlairFonville Because?

Comment: @Edenia because: "I am often getting zapped severely (to the extent I get muscle contractions)". It was intended to be a joke though.

Comment: @BlairFonville I see. Well, one thing to know when making English jokes - they don't always work with Bulgarian :) I even thought it is an insult haha. We say to mental people that they've been hit by electricity many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it buy my gut feeling is the breakdown of hotglue will be below 5kV

Some [high voltage electric tapes](https://www.google.com/search?q=high%20voltage%20insulating%20tape&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1) are rated up to ~70kV, make sure there is a continuous wrap that is clean as any residue on the tape could conduct. Any residue on the outside of the wire could also conduct.

The best way would be to get some [high voltage wire](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&ei=NRpIW-vgKI60tQXAhLHADQ&q=high%20voltage%20wire%20kv%20silicone&oq=high%20voltage%20wire%20kv%20silicone&gs_l=psy-ab.3...18467.21414.0.21590.13.13.0.0.0.0.253.1377.6j5j1.12.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.11.1282...0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1j33i22i29i30k1j33i160k1j33i21k1.0.QE3fVatoktk) that has a breakdown above that of the voltage you are experimenting with.

Comment: what about optical fiber cable? It is not conductive at all, but surely harder to implement.

Comment: The problem with that will be getting a wrap without gaps , even something smaller than a pinhole can leak out the electric charge as the air will conduct, it then forms a plasma and blows a hole through the insulation to some extent

Comment: 5kv is surely not sufficient, but if it is outside the wire insulation it could be beneficial at least to keep it from zapping me.
hotglue melts easily so it makes sense that it has a fairly subtle breakdown cap

Comment: Yes the ionized air is highly conductive, especially under my clothes, where the space is very small. I am almost always getting shocked if I put the wires under my clothes.

Comment: Also what about the wires coated with enamel

Comment: I’ve been zapped by static charged paint on grounded safety cages around a transformer insulation test at 100kV. Five meters away. It’s normal ion flow thru dust in the air from E fields

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Ouch, this sounds unpleasant.
Ion can move very well between small particles such as dust and even smoke (it contains small particles) or vapor (it contains water). My generator unit is 40kV, can't imagine 100kV, it gets into dangerous zone. Actually it gets into dangerous zone if it is just 20kV>

Comment: It was just the paint ( low pF)  no worse that neoprene shoes on a nylon carpet with ESD on a door knob.  If you wish to safeguard with a current limiting, add a current limiting with carbon sparkplug wire. 10k to 36kOhm/m.  I first noticed the silent discharges called Partial Discharge, PD on an AM radio. ... millions of research articles on this subject

Comment: It could have been much worse though. The paint is probably much less than 20pF.
Current is about 0.025-0.050~
limiting current will ultimately decrease voltage too, which I find for not nice. It looses the point of the voltage multiplier ladder inside the generator and I can decrease the output by other means already.
And if my skin gets less drier, I will just get back to point A haha

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist output as high as possible and safe as much as possible.

Comment: How about 100 kV 10uA

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist This would be fascinating.
Though it is expensive for me as I have to approximate it with 5 generators as I can find only 20kV ones in the market.
Another option would be to make my own, but I will need a very small, yet good step-up transformer and I don't have enough practice to even dare starting such a project.